# HTML - I need a Button, Label and TextBox with this last one AUTO RESIZE in WIDTH when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

I want to have a SEARCH div where I have a:
1) Button
2) Label
3) TextBox

**MY GOAL:**
The edit Box should automatically **resize to it's MAX WIDTH** by default and whenever I physically resize the browser page, without moving down !!!

I'm not even sure this is something you will want to use a **DIV** but here is what i have tried (and failed):

```
<div id="search">    
   <div id="searchbtn">
      <input id="btnSeach" type="button" value="Search" /> 
      Search:  
   </div>
   <div id="searchtxt">
       <input id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" type="text" value="" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
div#search
{
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #80808D;
   padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

div#searchbtn
{
   float: left;
   display: inline;
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

div#searchtxt
{
   float: left;
   width: auto;
   display: inline;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

I was hoping that the **width: auto** meant the div would auto-expand (rsss).

I tried putting a width of 90% on the TextBox but it never works well when resizing.
I tried putting some width on the **div searchtxt** but again didn't work properly when resizing.

If using **div** is the way forward, what would be the right **CSS** for the various DIVs?
If this is NOT the way ...then what other way would work better?

Thanks.

Comment: do u have any additional css to style these elements?

Comment: @Vinay  see updated original post

Comment: using `float: left;` shrinks those elements to the size of their contents.

Comment: @jnpcl OK ..so how do I tell the TEXT BOX (or it's related DIV) to auto-expand at it's maximum without moving down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some `display:` trickery...

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SwjDz/1/)** (Only tested in FireFox 3.6.x)

```
<style type="text/css">
div#search {
   border: 1px solid #80808D;
   display: table;
   height: 30px;
   padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

div#searchbtn {
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

div#searchtxt {
   display: table-cell;
   padding-right: 10px;
   width: 100%;
}
input#txtSearch {
   width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="search">
   <div id="searchbtn">
      <input id="btnSeach" type="button" value="Search" />
      Search:
   </div>
   <div id="searchtxt">
       <input id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note**: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the property values "inline-table", "run-in", **"table"**, "table-caption", **"table-cell"**, "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: My solution uses `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`, so yes you do (and should, regardless).

Comment: ..opps i just noticed, thanks for the quick response. So any specific DOCTYPE for this to work? And shall I put it for all browsers or i need to check the browser type?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `min-width` + % `width` to the div and then add `width:100%` to the input?

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/HtevS/

Comment: ..the idea looks good but on your text page, the TextBox is located below (does NOT stay on the same level as the Button).

Comment: Thanks ...i didnt't know there is a **min-width**  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found another method which would keep everything on the same line:

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/jtNEa/

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">
    <input id="btnSeach" type="button" value="Search" />
   <label for="txtSearch">Search</label>
   <input type="text"  name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" />
```

**CSS**

```
#search {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

label {
    padding-right:10px;
}

input {
  display:table-cell;
  width:95%;
}

label {
    display:table-cell;
    width:10px ; 
}
```

Comment: The button ...also seems to resize  :--)

Answer (score -1):

If you use CSS, you could have padding left and right so it would expand.

Comment: I believe "padding" just adds some extra px the sides, but does not automatically expand when i resize the browser.